# VB with SQL Connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I get an error when I try to connect to my database.
What I want to do is to check if I have on the same row from my DataBase a name and a surname

ex.  Id_ 1   Michael  Dawn

I have 2 textboxes and If they include:
Textbox1 - Michael
Textbox2 - Dawn

Then it's a positive match

I get an error :

[image: error]

Need some help with this one guys, thanks
Here is my code

Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form2

```
Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
Dim strQuery As String = ""
Dim SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
Dim DR As MySqlDataReader


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'just a message

    MsgBox(" You are searching for the users: " & vbCrLf & "Name: " & TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & "Surname: " & TextBox2.Text)


    ' connecting to the database

    dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost, Database = users, Uid = root, Pwd = password")
    strQuery = "SELECT users.name, users.surname" & _
        "WHERE users.name =  '" + TextBox1.Text + "'AND password = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'"

    SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

    'Database open

    Try
        dbCon.Open()
        DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        If DR.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Not a match", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            MsgBox("You guessed the correct name: " & TextBox1.Text & "and the surname: " & TextBox2.Text)
        End If


        'Close
        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Failure to communicate " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class[image: mySQL table]

Comment: Please copy & paste error message, my eyes can see there are few message boxes but it's hard to read them. BTW your **connection string seems wrong**, you have to separate fields with ";" instead of ",". Finally (sorry for long comment) I wouldn't inject directly user inputs in SQL code, even if you don't mind about malicious SQL injection that will fail with certain innocent user inputs...

Comment: Failed to communicate/
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: After replacing , with ;  at my mysqlconnection I get this error :
Failure to communicate
You have an error in your SQL syntax ; check your manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.name = " AND surname = "" at line 1

Comment: Please see my answer, your SELECT lacks of FROM statement too and you need an extra space before WHERE.